# Kubernetes edit svc vs edit service (is it editing the same file?)

Tags: kubernetes, docker-compose, kubernetes-pod

I installed kubernetes and it all looks alright I think.
( note that those are outputs after editing a file below, changing to NodePort)

```
sudo kubectl get deployment kubernetes-dashboard -n kubernetes-dashboard
NAME                   READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
kubernetes-dashboard   1/1     1            1           85m
```

and

```
sudo kubectl describe service kubernetes-dashboard -n kubernetes-dashboard
Name:                     kubernetes-dashboard
Namespace:                kubernetes-dashboard
Labels:                   k8s-app=kubernetes-dashboard
Annotations:              <none>
Selector:                 k8s-app=kubernetes-dashboard
Type:                     NodePort
IP Family Policy:         SingleStack
IP Families:              IPv4
IP:                       10.102.39.197
IPs:                      10.102.39.197
Port:                     <unset>  443/TCP
TargetPort:               8443/TCP
NodePort:                 <unset>  30306/TCP
Endpoints:                10.244.0.4:8443
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:
  Type    Reason  Age   From                Message
  ----    ------  ----  ----                -------
  Normal  Type    45m   service-controller  NodePort -> LoadBalancer
  Normal  Type    16m   service-controller  LoadBalancer -> NodePort
```

and

```
sudo kubectl get all -n kubernetes-dashboard
NAME                                             READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/dashboard-metrics-scraper-856586f554-5bps6   1/1     Running   0          69m
pod/kubernetes-dashboard-67484c44f6-dtc27        1/1     Running   0          69m

NAME                                TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)         AGE
service/dashboard-metrics-scraper   ClusterIP   10.107.30.72    <none>        8000/TCP        69m
service/kubernetes-dashboard        NodePort    10.102.39.197   <none>        443:30306/TCP   69m

NAME                                        READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/dashboard-metrics-scraper   1/1     1            1           69m
deployment.apps/kubernetes-dashboard        1/1     1            1           69m

NAME                                                   DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/dashboard-metrics-scraper-856586f554   1         1         1       69m
replicaset.apps/kubernetes-dashboard-67484c44f6        1         1         1       69m
```

and

```
sudo kubectl get all --all-namespaces
    NAMESPACE              NAME                                             READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
    kube-system            pod/coredns-558bd4d5db-9fxkw                     1/1     Running   0          71m
    kube-system            pod/coredns-558bd4d5db-bq79s                     1/1     Running   0          71m
    kube-system            pod/etcd-dyd-001                                 1/1     Running   0          71m
    kube-system            pod/kube-apiserver-dyd-001                       1/1     Running   0          71m
    kube-system            pod/kube-controller-manager-dyd-001              1/1     Running   0          71m
    kube-system            pod/kube-flannel-ds-amd64-hh5qm                  1/1     Running   0          71m
    kube-system            pod/kube-proxy-4pg4r                             1/1     Running   0          71m
    kube-system            pod/kube-scheduler-dyd-001                       1/1     Running   0          71m
    kubernetes-dashboard   pod/dashboard-metrics-scraper-856586f554-5bps6   1/1     Running   0          71m
    kubernetes-dashboard   pod/kubernetes-dashboard-67484c44f6-dtc27        1/1     Running   0          71m
    
NAMESPACE              NAME                                TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                  AGE
default                service/kubernetes                  ClusterIP   10.96.0.1       <none>        443/TCP                  71m
kube-system            service/kube-dns                    ClusterIP   10.96.0.10      <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP,9153/TCP   71m
kubernetes-dashboard   service/dashboard-metrics-scraper   ClusterIP   10.107.30.72    <none>        8000/TCP                 71m
kubernetes-dashboard   service/kubernetes-dashboard        NodePort    10.102.39.197   <none>        443:30306/TCP            71m

NAMESPACE     NAME                                     DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   NODE SELECTOR            AGE
kube-system   daemonset.apps/kube-flannel-ds-amd64     1         1         1       1            1           <none>                   71m
kube-system   daemonset.apps/kube-flannel-ds-arm       0         0         0       0            0           <none>                   71m
kube-system   daemonset.apps/kube-flannel-ds-arm64     0         0         0       0            0           <none>                   71m
kube-system   daemonset.apps/kube-flannel-ds-ppc64le   0         0         0       0            0           <none>                   71m
kube-system   daemonset.apps/kube-flannel-ds-s390x     0         0         0       0            0           <none>                   71m
kube-system   daemonset.apps/kube-proxy                1         1         1       1            1           kubernetes.io/os=linux   71m

NAMESPACE              NAME                                        READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
kube-system            deployment.apps/coredns                     2/2     2            2           71m
kubernetes-dashboard   deployment.apps/dashboard-metrics-scraper   1/1     1            1           71m
kubernetes-dashboard   deployment.apps/kubernetes-dashboard        1/1     1            1           71m

NAMESPACE              NAME                                                   DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
kube-system            replicaset.apps/coredns-558bd4d5db                     2         2         2       71m
kubernetes-dashboard   replicaset.apps/dashboard-metrics-scraper-856586f554   1         1         1       71m
kubernetes-dashboard   replicaset.apps/kubernetes-dashboard-67484c44f6        1         1         1       71m
```

Im following a tutorial to install Kubernetes dashboard.
https://k21academy.com/docker-kubernetes/kubernetes-dashboard/
This command will NOT show Kubernetes dashboard, it will show only kubernetes.

**In his example it showed kubernetes Metrics scraper and kubernetes dashboard, when I do it it only shows kubernetes. I don't know why**

```
sudo kubectl get svc

    NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
    kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1    <none>        443/TCP   44m
```

And because of that I can only edit kubernetes with the following command, but I don't want to edit kubernetes. I want to edit service/kubernetes-dashboard instead.

Works but not the correct file I think:

```
sudo kubectl edit service/kubernetes
```

Does not work:

```
sudo kubectl edit service/kubernetes-dashboard
```

So had used this command instead to edit Kubernetes-dashboard
but im not sure if they are the same files:

```
sudo kubectl -n kubernetes-dashboard edit svc kubernetes-dashboard
```

**Question Nr 1.**

Why is kubernetes Dashboard and metrics scraper not showing up when I use this command? And how do I make it show up?

```
sudo kubectl get svc
```

**Question Nr 2.**

Are those two commands editing the same file?

```
sudo kubectl edit service/kubernetes-dashboard
```

And

```
sudo kubectl -n kubernetes-dashboard edit svc kubernetes-dashboard
```

**Question Nr 3.**

If the file I edited with :
sudo kubectl -n kubernetes-dashboard edit svc kubernetes-dashboard
Is not the same files that is being edited when I use this command:

```
sudo kubectl edit service/kubernetes-dashboard
```

How do I fix or revert the changes I made with the first command if im not sure how it previously looked like?
Can I delete the file somehow and regenerate it after applying the recommended?

Im trying to install the dashboard and im not getting an external IP.

Comment: you are using `-n kubernetes-dashboard` , other is in `default` namespace. This means, the same resource is deployed in two different namespaces. So if you edit the manifest of one, you are not changing the manifest of other!!!

Comment: Oh Snap. How do I revert to the original file that I wrongly changed with sudo kubectl -n kubernetes-dashboard edit svc kubernetes-dashboard?? Im not sure how the file originally looked like!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you installed `dashboard` you used the following command.

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/v2.0.0/aio/deploy/recommended.yaml $ kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/v2.0.0-beta8/aio/deploy/recommended.yaml
```

If you open the `recommended.yaml` you will find out that it is using `namespace` as
`kubernetes-dashboard`. Eg:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  labels:
    k8s-app: kubernetes-dashboard
  name: kubernetes-dashboard
```

**Answer Nr 2:** NO, You are mixing the namespaces, for few of the commands you have used `default` namespace. However, for the others you have used `kubernetes-dashboard` namespace.

Are those two commands editing the same file?

```
sudo kubectl edit service/kubernetes-dashboard
```

And

```
sudo kubectl -n kubernetes-dashboard edit svc kubernetes-dashboard
```

Answer Nr 3: Same as answer#2. You need to use consistent namespace.

To revert back:

You need delete the resources you created on default namespaces and be consistent with the namespaces.  Also, to start fresh, you can use `kubectl delete -f <same path as used for installation>` to clean the stuff.

```
kubectl delete -f  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/v2.0.0/aio/deploy/recommended.yaml
kubectl delete -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/v2.0.0-beta8/aio/deploy/recommended.yaml
```

Eg:

```
kubectl delete -f  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/v2.0.0/aio/deploy/recommended.yaml
namespace "kubernetes-dashboard" deleted
serviceaccount "kubernetes-dashboard" deleted
service "kubernetes-dashboard" deleted
secret "kubernetes-dashboard-certs" deleted
secret "kubernetes-dashboard-csrf" deleted
secret "kubernetes-dashboard-key-holder" deleted
configmap "kubernetes-dashboard-settings" deleted
role.rbac.authorization.k8s.io "kubernetes-dashboard" deleted
clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io "kubernetes-dashboard" deleted
rolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io "kubernetes-dashboard" deleted
clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io "kubernetes-dashboard" deleted
deployment.apps "kubernetes-dashboard" deleted
service "dashboard-metrics-scraper" deleted
deployment.apps "dashboard-metrics-scraper" deleted
```

Comment: You are totally right. I just figured out I can add the namespace and I can edit it!! with: sudo kubectl edit service/kubernetes-dashboard -n kubernetes-dashboard But how do I now delete and recreate the stock file I messed up when using sudo kubectl -n kubernetes-dashboard edit svc kubernetes-dashboard

Comment: you can delete the objects using `kubectl delete svc kubernetes-dashboard` from default namespace.

Comment: And then I can just reinstall it from scratch? with apply recommended?

Comment: I would suggest: 1) `kubectl delete svc kubernetes-dashboard` and then 2) `kubectl delete -f  /SAME/PATH/USED/FOR/ISTALLATION` , then do fresh installation.

Comment: I will just not sure where it was installed in the first place. I used the commands from here to install it. Do you know where it is installed? https://gist.github.com/BeerOnBeard/ebe63521607aa0db3851c39a5760489b

Comment: see edited answer with two `kubectl delete -f ....`